# Oracle: Multiple joins with group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm not very familiar with SQLs. I'm using oracle.

Here are the example tables:

```
-----------------------
Table A:
A_ID, A_NAME, A_Address
-----------------------
Table B:
A_ID, B_Name,     
-----------------------
Table C:
B_Name, C_Title
-----------------------
```

The output should be 
A_ID, A_Name, A_Address, Count(C_Title),

every B_name corresponds to C_Title   (basically a lookup)

Please guide

Comment: Do you want the number of rows in b or the sum of b_quantity? You should probably add some sample data and show some attempts that you made that failed.

Comment: just edited the need.. maybe that makes thing clearer. I just need count of rows in A join with B on A_ID and then B_Name lookup from C wsing B_Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM A;

 A_ID A_NAME     A_ADDRESS
---------- ---------- ----------
     1 RAM        MO
     2 SITA       MI
     3 JANAKI     IL


SELECT * FROM B;

 A_ID B_NAME  
---------- ----------
     1 PAUL
     1 KAPIL
     2 DAVE

SELECT * FROM C;

B_NAME     C_TITLE
---------- ----------
KAPIL      HONDA
KAPIL      MAZDA
KAPIL      ODYSSY
DAVE       BENZE
DAVE       LIMOUSINE

SELECT a.A_ID, a.A_Name, a.A_Address, b.B_Name, Count(C_Title)
FROM A a 
INNER JOIN B b ON(a.A_ID = b.A_ID)
INNER JOIN C c ON(b.B_Name=c.B_Name)
GROUP BY a.A_ID, a.A_Name, a.A_Address, b.B_Name;



A_ID A_NAME     A_ADDRESS  B_NAME     COUNT(C_TITLE)
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------
     2 SITA       MI         DAVE                    2
     1 RAM        MO         KAPIL                   3
```

Here, I consider that B_Name in table C have reputation values(as it is a foreign key) and the A_ID in A, B_Name in B are Primary Keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A_ID, A_Name, A_Address, Count(C_Title)
FROM TableA a 
INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.A_ID = b.A_ID
INNER JOIN TableC c ON b.B_Name = c.B_Name
GROUP BY A_ID, A_Name, A_Address
```